# Git pull from from other repo and push changes to current repo

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I'm trying to `pull` contents from `Repo1` and push those contents to `RepoX`.

Below are the commands I've used so far,

```
git remote add Repo1 [repo1 url]
git pull Repo1 feature/branceName
```

With the above commands I could successfully pull contents from `Repo1` to `RepoX`.

Issue here is, When I query the `git status` it shows below message:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Git is not displaying the contents which I pulled from `Repo1`. How do I push the contents to `RepoX`?

Comment: Please define your terms a bit more. What are Repo1 and RepoX? Both are remotes? I would expect that from your first sentence but..... just after that you're expecting RepoX to somehow get contents from your pull... if RepoX is a remote it won't be updated by your pull. You just pulled in one of your local branches.

Comment: Repo1 and RepoX are both Remote branches, I pull contents from Repo1 to my local, now i need to push the contents to repoX

Comment: Could you add the output of something like "git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all"?

Comment: I'm sure you're just misunderstanding the messages. There is nothing to commit, because, [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) merges the upstream.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are referring to remotes as opposed to branches, considering this is what your example shows.

---

**Add both remotes to your repository**

*NOTE: Each remote has their own branches. Preferred method of sync between two remotes would probably be Fork instead of doing this work manually.*

```
git remote add Repo1 [repo1 url]
git remote add Repo2 [repo2 url]
```

**Checkout a branch from one remote**

```
git checkout Repo1/master
```

This means you pulled changes from one remote locally.

**Push a branch to the other remote**

```
git push Repo2/master
```

In case your history differs on both remotes, you will unfortunately need to force push.

```
git push -f Repo2/master
```

**Alternative solution**

As an alternative, you can set your git config to always pull from one remote, and to push to the other one. Note sure if this has sense at all, but it is ok to note this option exists.

Once you add both of your remotes, your primary remote will automatically be set for both push and pull. You can overwrite the push config with:

```
git remote set-url --push Repo2 [repo2 url]
```

---

In case you are really talking about branches, then the situation is far simpler, depending on what you need. You can merge the branch1 into branch2 or rebase it.

**Merge**

```
git checkout branch1
git pull
git checkout branch2
git pull
git merge branch1
```

This will pull all changes from both remote branches and merge the branch1 into branch2. This is done via a merge commit that will include all changes.

**Rebase**

In case you want to have specific commits also pulled into your branch, then you need to use rebase.

```
git checkout branch1
git pull
git checkout branch2
git pull
git rebase branch1
```

Instead of having a merge commit, this will include all of the separate commits from b1 into b2.

Comment: i tried this `git checkout Repo1/master` i get this error `error: pathspec 'repo1/develop' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: Can you let me know a result of: `git remote -v`

Comment: origin https://xxw2@bitbucket.devnet.com/scm/~x079152/internalreview.git (fetch)

origin https://xxw2@bitbucket.devnet.com/scm/~x079152/internalreview.git (push)

Repo1 https://xxw2@bitbucket.devnet.com/scm/bw/repo1.git (fetch)

Repo1 https://xxw2@bitbucket.devnet.com/scm/bw/repo1.git (push)

Comment: Ok it seems that develop branch is possibly not present on the Repo1 remote (which is funny if you tried to checkout master). We can check this by entering: `git remote -v show Repo1`. This will return a list of all branches for that remote.

Comment: it shows `develop                         new (next fetch will store in remotes/repo1)`

Comment: Then you can't do `git checkout Repo1/master` as the only branches that exist on that remote are: devleop and new. Your options are `git checkout Repo1/develop` or `git checkout Repo1/new`

Comment: event that i get the same error like `error:pathspec`

Comment: Did you use git fetch on that remote at least once? The problem is most probably that your local git tracker doesn't know that this branch exists, even if you do.

You can fetch from all remotes by using: `git fetch --all `

After doing so, try to checkout again.

Comment: it worked, i'm not seeing that error any more. Now i did `git remote set-url --push Repo2 [repo2 url]
` and `git push -u origin master;` i get this `Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date` my code is not pushed to remote repoX

Comment: you need to do `git push -u Repo1 master`. Origin is the first remote that you use for pulling  the code, and Repo1 is the remote that you are trying to push, right?

Comment: No i need to push it to RepoX (Origin). I fetched content from Repo1, i could see in my local repo now i need to push it to origin

Comment: Fetch only syncs the changes, it does not pull them locally. You need to `pull` (which does fetch + pull)  the changes from repo1 then, before pushin to Repox.